# Does Tesla K80 GPU support int8

Tags: deep-learning, cuda, gpu

Hi I am trying to deploy DL models on tesla k80 GPU that are int8 quantized my question is does it support int8 and is a good go for it?

Answer (score 2):

Tesla K80 does not have any hardware support for int8 calculations.

int8 hardware support in CUDA GPUs was first [introduced in the pascal generation](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/new-pascal-gpus-accelerate-inference-in-the-data-center/)

Later, it was introduced in the Tensor Core unit in [the Turing generation](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-turing-architecture-in-depth/)

Recent CUDA architecture generation naming in chronological order is like this:

```
Fermi, Kepler, Maxwell, Pascal, Volta, Turing, Ampere, Hopper/Ada Lovelace
```

K80 is a member of the Kepler generation.